# Change the size of X/ Y labels in a ggplot with unusual arguments

Tags: ggplot2, resize, label

I aim at increasing the labels in size in a graph that is maybe a bit unusual because:

- I desired to plot the zero values in red and used

  `aes (color = mm3 == 0)) +`

  `scale_colour_manual(values = c(`TRUE`= "red",`FALSE`= 'black'))`

to accomplish this.

I've tried using:

- theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),
  axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"))

this did not seem to have any effect. And also

- theme_grey(base_size = 22)

This increased label sizes, but influenced the graph coloring and added an unwanted legend to the graph.

This is the code:

```
   ggplot(Rodeococha, aes(x=`Age BP`,y=mm3)) +
    geom_bar(size=1,linetype=1,stat="identity", aes (color = mm3 == 0)) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c(`TRUE` = "red",`FALSE` = 'black')) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 8000), breaks=c(0,1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000)) +
    scale_x_reverse() +
    ggtitle("Charcoal Abundance") + 
  labs(y= "Volume (mm3/cm3)", x = "Time(yrs. BP)") +
         theme_ipsum()+
         theme(legend.position = "none") +
         coord_flip()`
```

- I am unable to add an image, because of Stack Overflow's community rules. And am not really sure how to make a minimum reproducible example for this. So, maybe it helps to note it is a barplot on its side, with reversed values on the initial x-axis. It plots +100 zero values in red dots and a few peaks in black. Hopefully, you guys have some suggestions!

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. You *can!!* include an image. It will just not be displayed. We can embed it for you then.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you can make a minimal reproducible example by sharing some data - even a dummy dataset.  Regardless, here's an example that hopefully shows you two approaches that could work.  One is more recommended than the other (since it uses some Tidy Data principles), but both do get the same result.

Dataset for both is:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=rnorm(100))
# basic point plot:
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Let's say our goal is to plot the same plot, but color in points so that negative y values are blue and positive y values are red.  How do we do it?

#### In-line Evaluation of Data

You can evaluate in-line kind of like you are suggesting with your code.  It works, but is a bit more complicated to get the same result and is sort of clunky.  It does work though using either the expression in-line (if you use that approach, I'd recommend using `aes(color= eval(...))`), but that means you have more work on the backend using `scale_color_manual`.  It's a bit better to use `ifelse()`, which let's you set the labels of the values right in the `aes()` function:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point(aes(color=ifelse(y<0,'Small Stuff', 'Big Stuff'))) +
    scale_color_manual("Type of Stuff", values=list('Big Stuff'='red','Small Stuff'='blue'))
```

[image]

Note that the `scale_color_manual` function is used to set the name of the legend.  Since I know my label names as a result of using `ifelse()`, I know that I can set my colors properly too.

#### Tidy Data Approach

The better approach is built around using `dplyr`, `tidyr` and generally what is referred to as [Tidy Data Principles](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  This approach would suggest that you add a column in your dataset to be used when plotting later.  It's a lot "safer" that way so you are not mixing data preparation with plotting, and it's then way easier to plot later on.  Here we first adjust the dataset:

```
df$stuff <- ifelse(df$y < 0, 'Small Stuff', 'Big Stuff')
```

And then the plot function is this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
    geom_point(aes(color=stuff)) +
    scale_color_manual("Type of Stuff", values=list('Big Stuff'='red', 'Small Stuff'='blue'))
```

In this case, both approaches are about the same amount of code.  In more complicated examples, the Tidy approach is generally better, but here go with either route.

As applied to your system?... hard to say without sharing the dataset or the plot.  Is it just the name of the legend?  You can set that in your `scale_color_...` function or with `labs(color=...`.